# WebServices that will work as a single DLL .Class Library?or WCF service library?

Tags: .net, web-services, dll, dynamics-nav

I am about to start developing Web Services that will work as a middle layer between Dynamics NAV and another entity that will expose some Services.
The goal is to be able to create a single DLL that will be installed in their machines (Dynamics NAV team)that will allow them to call my webservices and i will communicate with that other entity that will make the services available, i will handle the response and i send back to Dynamics NAV. Therefore i will need to create a Class library? but as far as i know i can't add a service reference in a Class Library project correct?

I will need to add the Service Reference because i will need to communicate with the endpoint that will expose the webservices for me to consume.

Dynamics NAV is going to install that DLL and will invoke my Services sending a XML.

What is your opinion what's the best approach?

Comment: Of course you can add a service reference from a DLL.

Comment: when i create a Class Library solution, over my project when i do right click over my project i only see the options "New Item" , "Existing Item", "New Folder", "Reference" and "Connected Service", i don't see the option "add Service Reference"

Comment: I can only agree with @CodingYoshi. Of course you can. What’s your VS version?

Comment: Right click on the `References` option and you will see the option.